# rails has_many minimum collection size update validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `has_many` association that accepts nested attributes.  I need for there to be a minimum of 1 associated object in the collection, so I wrote a custom validator:

```
class MinimumCollectionSizeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.size < options[:size]
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must have at least #{options[:size]} line.")
    end
  end
end
```

The model looks like:

```
has_many :foos, :dependent=>:destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foos
validates :foos, :minimum_collection_size=>{:size=>1}
```

This works great on model creation, but fails miserable on update.  `@my_model.update_attributes(params[:my_model])` returns true even if all the foos are removed by _destroy.

How do I get `update_attributes` to behave the same as `save`?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A better way to validate the minimum size of a collection:

```
validates :my_association, :length => { :minimum => Fixnum}
```

Comment: I had an experience with using this, that does fullfill exactly what I wanted. So for creating an object with only validates if the object has the minimum defined. But if lets say the minimum is 2, and after creation I delete one of those associations, it saves and validates the object with 1. I dont know why is that but I wanted the validation not work only for creation.

Comment: This validator counts object that are marked for destruction as well. Its better to use custom [validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) and count non marked for destruction with: answers.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count < MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS

Comment: This validation fails if you're using nested attributes with allow_destroy because it counts occurrences marked for destruction.

Comment: This is solution has problem when you delete last record in collection. Below I write better solution.

Comment: @duleorlovic, @Brooks it's no longer a case. In **Rails 5** new `ActiveRecord`'s [length validator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/length.rb#L3-L10) was introduced which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 25):

SooDesuNe

Yes, `validates :foos, :length => {:minimum => 1, :message=>"At least one foo" }` is better than the original one, but the same issue still happens.

To fix it, we could use validate method:

```
validate :validate_foos

private
def validate_foos
  remaining_foos = foos.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)
  errors.add :foos, "At least one foo" if remaining_foos.empty?
```

Hope it helps to who encountered the same problem.

Comment: You can customize the min/max messages with `too_short` and `too_long`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_length_of

Answer (score 13):

Create validator:

```
class CollectionLengthValidator < ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    value = value.respond_to?(:reject) ? value.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?) : value
    super(record, attribute, value)
  end
end
```

This is resolve problem with delete last record in collection.

Then use in model as standard length validator:

```
validates :foos, :collection_length => {:minimum => 1}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Thank you! And it also works when making valiations in Reform forms instead of relying on accepts_nested_attributes