# Validate the number of has_many items in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, tagging, has-many

Users can add tags to a snippet:

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relationships
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  belongs_to :closing_reason

end
```

I want to validate the number of tags: at least 1, at most 6. How am I about to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can always create a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Something like

```
  validate :validate_tags

  def validate_tags
    errors.add(:tags, "too much") if tags.size > 5
  end
```

Comment: I would probably use `tags.count` so that the DB does the work and you don't load all the tags just for this one validation.

Comment: @Beerlington: In fact it seems that Nikita is right, you don't want to hit the database for a validation, you want to check the actual length of "tags" of the object.

Comment: If you use tags.size, it does the "right" thing. see http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size

Comment: This stops working when you create a Tag that references an existing Snippet.

What you should do is attach a `validate: true` to the `belongs_to` relationship. Not to mention Rails has built in length validation with `validates_length_of`.

Comment: I don't think this is thread-safe - is it? What happens if two workers try to insert tags?

Comment: validates_numericality_of :next_release, :less_than => 6  Just wanting to let the next reader know there's a better way.

Comment: @baash05 the `length` validator is appropriate here, not the `numericality` validator. Tags respond to `length` and aren't a number explicitly.

Answer (score 85):

A better solution has been provided by [@SooDesuNe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64709/soodesune) on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098987/1106878)

```
validates :tags, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 6 }
```

Comment: FWIW, the default error message for this is "is too long (maximum is 100 characters)"

Comment: If you want to add a custom error message: validates :tags, length: { minimum: 1, message: "are required. Please add at least one." }

Comment: An even nicer way for validation messages is to override the `too_long` validation message for that model's attribute in a locale (e. g. `en.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.tags.too_long`) so you don't have to handle the translations by hand in the model itself.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can validate with using `.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length`.

How about this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups do
    def length
      reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length
    end
  end
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups, allow_destroy: true
  validates :groups, length: { maximum: 5 }
end
```

Or this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups, allow_destroy: true
  GROUPS_MAX_LENGTH = 5
  validate length_of_groups

  def length_of_groups
    groups_length = 0
    if groups.exists?
      groups_length = groups.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length
    end
    errors.add(:groups, 'too many') if groups_length > GROUPS_MAX_LENGTH
  end
end
```

Then, you can command.

```
@user.assign_attributes(params[:user])
@user.valid?
```

Thank you for reading.

References:

http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/
http://qiita.com/asukiaaa/items/4797ce44c3ba7bd7a51f

Comment: I had no idea about the ability to pass a block to association methods. That is phenomenal, thank you.

Comment: Two years later: the `length` method in the block is actually never called. A block passed to `has_many` is actually called an extension. You can create new "finders, creators and other factory-type methods" with it.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many