# Best way to implement has_n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design

How would you implement a `has_n` association on Rails for a given `n`? Let's say for example a rugby team. It has 15 players. Would you implement it as `has_many` and check in before save to make sure it has 15 players, or would you prefer to implement it as 15 `belongs_to`? Note that the order is important in this case.

Comment: I think your question is directly related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4836897/22371).

Comment: I don't think it's directly related. That question uses a join table. No need for that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect your request for ordering...

You'll need to add a sort_key to the players table. You can use an integer, but a float is always a more flexible choice. Then use the `:order => "sort_key"` phrase.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, :order => "sort_key", :inverse_of => :team
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, :inverse_of => :players

  validate :validate_players_count, :on => :create
  def validate_players_count
    if team.players.size > 15
      errors[:base] << "a team can only have 15 players"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Then how would you change the player on the first position to the one in the forth?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the ordering request.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed. Now to change two players from positions all I have to do is update the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make it by `has_many` and validate players quantity when adding a new player.

I think that is the right way to make one-to-many relation.