# validate presence of nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many photos that belong to a `Movie` like `Movie.photos`

Any idea how can I validate that a Movie should have at least one photo?

`validates_presence_of :photos` doesn't work or at least is considering `nil` as valid.

I'm interested in validate against a real nested object.

Comment: Does not this solved your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836897/validate-the-number-of-has-many-items-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in validator for this, like presence_of, so you can just write your own. The following goes in your movie.rb file.

```
validate :at_least_one_photo

private


def at_least_one_photo
  if photos.size < 1
    errors.add :base, "The movie must have at least one photo attached before saving"
  end
end
```