# Restrict user to have just two associations, rather than wide association has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want that each user in my app have possibility to add **just two** pictures, but just one is visible, so i added a column named "visible" to my pictures table :

```
def change
   create_table :pictures do |t|
     t.string :picture
     t.boolean :visible, default: true
     t.timestamps
   end
end
```

then i need something like :

```
user has_two :pictures
```

finally i need that if he add a second picture, the first one should be set to visibile=false and the new one to visible=true.

When he try to add another picture (3th) i should replace the picture which has `visibile == true` by the new

what is the way to do something like this, and how i can implement (`has_two`) association

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate the number of has\_many items in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836897/validate-the-number-of-has-many-items-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @depa my question is not about validation essentially,but about how to manipulate two pictures, say if user add a first picture it will be his profile photo, if he add a second picture, the "visible" column of the first one will be set to false (to be invisible) and the second picture will be his new picture profile

Comment: all this in internal without that user know about if how many pictures can add at the time, so don't need validation, what user know is that he have possibility to add one pic

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to handle this

### Validation

```
class User
  MAX_PHOTOS_PER_PERSON = 2
  has_many :photos
  validate_on_create :photos_count_within_bounds

  def visible_photo
    photos.find(&:visible)
  end

  private

  def photos_count_within_bounds
    return if photos.blank?
    errors.add("Only #{MAX_PHOTOS_PER_PERSON} photos allowed per person") if photos.length > MAX_PHOTOS_PER_PERSON 
  end
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :album
  validates_associated :album
end
```

### Two associations

If you are sure that you just need two photos per person, you can go for a more simple solution of two has_one associations

```
class User
  has_one :visible_photo, class_name: 'Photo', -> { where visible: true }
  has_one :spare_photo, class_name: 'Photo', -> { where visible: false }

  def add_photo(details)
    self.create_spare_photo(...details...)
  end

  def activate_spare_photo
    visible_photo.deactivate if visible_photo
    spare_photo.activate if spare_photo
    # At this point, visible_photo will contain the earlier spare_photo
  end
end

class Photo
  def activate
    self.visible = true
    self.save!
  end

  def deactivate
   self.visible = false
   self.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @RajeshKolappakam, thank for your answer, i like the second suggestion, but how to do if i want manipulate it, for example if i want to create a new photo what i should do : user.build_visible_photo or user.build_spare_photo or what ... ?

Comment: how to apply it with my case

Comment: Yes, these are like any other `has_one` associations now. So you can use the `build..` methods like you mentioned.

Comment: should i add some foreign key ? or just still using my photos table with user_id foreign key, please can you add more details to your answer to be more clear

Comment: No need to add a foreign key as `Photo.user_id` should still work. Why don't you give it a try and let me know if you see any problems?

Comment: ok ;) but by what i should began !! any one should i use in my new action, the first relation or the second ? i want that user when he add a photo the first time, it should be invisible,then if he activate it it should be visible, i'm confusing here, if for example i use user.build_spare_photo then user activate it, false become true but not logic that spare_photo have true as value !!