# rails, how to validate that an associated record exists before saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

Groups, and then GroupMembers.

I don't want a group to be allowed to be saved there is at least one groupmember model associated via a build.

how can I do that in the model? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [rails has_many minimum collection size update validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486749/rails-has-many-minimum-collection-size-update-validation)